# jquery-ias loading next page too soon

Tags: jquery

I'm using this plugin http://infiniteajaxscroll.com for an infinite scroll for users' posts on my website. It worked swimmingly when I first installed it a few days ago, but I've just realized that it's loading the next page on one click of the mouse's scroll wheel, or even I adjust the scroll bar down even the tiniest fraction. I set my pagination to 1 post per page, and IAS is loading a second post instantly, and continues to load a new post for each fraction I scroll. The problem is that it'll load thousands of posts before I even get to the bottom of the page. I tried removing all other javascript from the page, and I tried removing different components of the post just to see if anything was interfering with the IAS plugin, but nothing seems to resolve this bug. It didn't do this when I first installed it, and I haven't changed anything relating to it directly since - so could there be something that's interfering with it?

Comment: First thing you should do is see if the problem is reproducible. Make a jsfiddle of it and if it happens there too, post it so we have something to go off of. If you can't reproduce it, then you know it's something specific to your page's design/layout/scripts. At that point I would start removing css/html/js from the page to narrow down what is causing the problem.

Answer (score 0):

This might happen if your container contains images with a non-fixed height. Try to set the height attribute on your images, or initialize Infinite AJAX Scroll after the images have loaded.